# C Program to Identify whether file is ELF

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a C program which will read directories and find out only ELF files.
So that the checksums of these files will be calculated and if someone tampers these files, a notification will be sent.

With stat system call there is no way to find the ELF type of file.

Could you please let me know how to find the ELF files in a particular directory.

Thanks.